# MD5 hash property in eclipse artifacts xml file

Tags: eclipse, pde, md5sum

I am in the middle of generating update site for my eclipse plugin.
Currently, I am using Eclipse PDE build process to generate a site consisting of 3 features including the feature created by me consisting of details regarding 6 bundles and the features representing GMF runtime SDK and GMF tooling SDK.

But instead of putting all the plugins and features related to GMF runtime SDK and GMF tooling SDK in the plugins and feature folder respectively of the update site , I want them to get installed from eclipse site.

However the MD5 hash that is being generated in the artifacts.xml file seems to be creating some trouble and I am getting "MD5 hash is not as expected" errors.

My basic purpose is to install GMF runtime SDK and GMF tooling SDK along with the installation of my plugin since both of them are required for the proper functioning of my plugin.

Could you please guys help?

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well got the answer to my question.

In my feature.xml file , I added GMF runtime and tooling as dependancies.

Hence during installation , Eclipse takes care of installing the required

plugins i.e GMF runtime and tooling for the proper functioning of my plugin.